# could not install Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am trying to install Azure Cli on Mac.

I use

```
brew update && brew install azure-cli
```

However, it stuck at

```
==> Installing dependencies for azure-cli: rust
==> Installing azure-cli dependency: rust
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/rust/1.59.0 --enable-vendor --release-channel=stable
==> make
```

Comment: Is it stuck, or does it just take a long time?

Comment: I don't know. Should I just wait? Installing azure should not take that long, right?

Comment: I would say no. I just tried installing the CLI myself, and it took about 47 seconds. What's strange about your output is that Homebrew seems to have to build Rust from source, and I have no idea why. I wonder what would happen if you [installed Rust](https://rustup.rs/) first?

Comment: Update: I don't think that's it. I just uninstalled Rust, and `azure-cli` installed OK.

Comment: so I am using brew install rust. And it is still taking forever...  and the message is "==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/rust/1.59.0 --enable-vendor --release
==> make" again... I will just wait?

Comment: Yes, I guess that's your best bet...

Comment: I used ```curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh``` to install the rust. And I saw the welcome to rust message.  And then I run brew install azure-cli and got stuck again.

Comment: I just pip installed azure Cli and it is completed! https://pypi.org/project/azure-cli/#description

Comment: HI, I'm having the same problem. I'm stuck at "make". Did you stop it in the end or not?

Answer (score 1):

#### Steps to install Azure CLI on Mac OS:

Install the **Azure CLI** with ***homebrew package manager***. it keeps your **CLI** up to date. its officially tested with **macOS** version **10.9** and later.

As you already followed this

```sh
brew update && brew install azure-cli
```

Before doing this make **note** of it.

**Azure CLI has a dependency on the Homebrew python@3.10 package, we need to install it**.

```sh
brew update && brew install python@3.10 && brew upgrade python@3.10 
brew link --overwrite python@3.10
```

So, after installing the **python@3.10** version you can use the **pip/brew command to install the Azure CLI**.

Refer **[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-macos)** for more information.